# IEEE -754 Floating Point Conversion

Tags: floating-point, binary

Just started a new class and I'm having trouble grasping the floating-point conversions. We were given a problem of a dollar amount, then to convert that to binary, then to hex, then to floating point. I can find the answers online in calculators if i wanted, but I need help understanding how logically for a fraction number.

I can do the following for ex: 842 to binary(no fraction), how would you convert something like 272.10, or anything along those lines? And then how to floating point?

I was under the impression you take 2,7,2,1,0 and run that in the binary value chart, corresponding with 0010, 0111, 0010, 0001, 0000.. but that's not what everything has for the final answer.

The community helped me a lot with the hex and made that easy, hoping to grasp this as well. Any step-by-step help is appreciated.

Comment: Floating point numbers are stored very differently to integers (whole numbers).
The typically store the sign, exponent and mantissa. Wikipedia has a useful section for this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Internal_representation

Comment: The format you mention, i.e. `0010, 0111, 0010, 0001, 0000...` is generally called BCD (binary coded digits) and is not the same as floating point.

Answer (score 0):

This is an extended comment rather than a complete answer, only addressing "I was under the impression you take 2,7,2,1,0 and run that in the binary value chart, corresponding with 0010, 0111, 0010, 0001, 0000.. but that's not what everything has for the final answer."

If you have been able to convert decimal 842 to binary, you must have noticed that both decimal and binary are positional systems. The "8" contributes eight hundred to the total value, not just eight, because of its position.

In the same way, the "1" in decimal 272.10 contributes one tenth to the total value. To do the conversion, you must not just map digits to their individual binary representation, you also need to map their weighting by a power of the radix, ten for decimal, two for binary.

Unfortunately, one tenth cannot be represented exactly as a terminating binary fraction, so any radix 2 representation of 272.10 must be an approximation. This is the same problem as representing 1/3 as a terminating decimal fraction.